# xhtml validator

Tags: xhtml

why w3 validator show error?

```
"Line 5, Column 7: end tag for "head" which is not finished

</head>

Most likely, you nested tags and closed them in the wrong order. For example <p><em>...</p> is not acceptable, as <em> must be closed before <p>. Acceptable nesting is: <p><em>...</em></p>

Another possibility is that you used an element which requires a child element that you did not include. Hence the parent element is "not finished", not complete. For instance, in HTML the <head> element must contain a <title> child element, lists require appropriate list items (<ul> and <ol> require <li>; <dl> requires <dt> and <dd>), and so on.
"
```

My code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    Text...
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you read the full error explanation?

> For instance, in HTML the `<head>` element must contain a `<title>` child
>   element

Looks like you don't have the `<title>` element.